# Phoenix Framework - jQuery connection

Tags: jquery, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have problem with jquery connection to my Project on the Phoenix Framework. I have installed jQuery through npm install

> npm i jquery

I add import to app.js.

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

My dependencies at package.json

```
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"phoenix": "file:../deps/phoenix",
"phoenix_html": "file:../deps/phoenix_html"
```

But in console I have error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

My js

```
<script>
    $("#login-btn").click(function(){
        console.log("Sign in button pressed");
    });
</script>
```

Please, help me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this line to assets/webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery"
  })
]
```

and assets/js/app.js

```
import $ from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = $
window.$ = $
```

Answer (score 0):

When you import jQuery, it is only available in that module. It doesn't get automatically set on the window object, which is where it gets searched in that `script` tag.

I am not sure if it's a good practice, but in your specific case you can try to do something like:

```
import {$, jQuery} from 'jquery';

window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

Comment: I tried to use your fix, unfortunately it does not work

Comment: @ДенисКорх Are you sure that your phoenix's `app.js` is run before your custom script tag?

Comment: So far I have solved the problem like this:
I connected scripts before rendering the templates: 

      <script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_static ..."></script>
      <%= render ... %>

And add to app.js your fix: 

    import $ from 'jquery'; 
    window.jQuery = $; 
    window.$ = $;